# Component re-renders when using react-navigation for react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I noticed that whenever I navigate to another page using the navigate props available to my component, it triggers a re-render of the component and componentDidMount is being called whenever I navigate to a screen that has rendered before.

For instance, when I navigate a user to their profile page and they decided to go back to the dashboard, the dashboard component which has been initially rendered is being rendered again and componentDidMount is being called thereby slowing down the application.

```
 import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

    const Routes = StackNavigator({
      home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
      },
      dashboard: {
        screen: Dashboard
      },
      profile: {
        screen: Profile
      }
    },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      });
```

In my component I navigate the user with `this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName')`

I would appreciate any help to stop the component from re-rendering when navigating back to it. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that your screens are Stateful, add a `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method that returns `false` if you do not want a re-render.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How about on initial render, I would like the component to be normally rendered only when the user is navigating back to it after the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a state variable in your constructor that keeps track if you navigated.  State is only relevant to the current component.  So if you navigate to 'ScreenName' multiple times, the stack builds and each ScreenName component has its own state.

```
 constructor(props)
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       navigatedAway : false
    }
```

Then before you navigate to your 'ScreenName' screen update the state

```
  this.setState({
    navigatedAway : true
  },
  () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName');
  }
);
```

Use syntax above to make sure state isUpdated THEN navigate.  Then like Dan said in comments above if your function **shouldComponentUdate** have a condition statement.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(newProps){
    // return true if you want to update
    // return false if you do not
}
```

*** Side Note ***

When you navigate I don't believe the component is unmounted.  You could verify this by simply printing to console.  Correct me if I am wrong though, I am fairly new to react native.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("COMPONENT_CONTENT_MOUNTED")
}

componentWillUnmount({
    console.log("COMPONENT_CONTENT_UNMOUNTED")
 }
```

Comment: ComponentDidMount is being called and I can see the console logs I added to it. I like your approach anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using React Navigation 5.X, just do the following:

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'

export default function App(){

const isFocused = useIsFocused()

    useEffect(() => {
        //Update the state you want to be updated
    } , [isFocused])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, when you navigate away, the component is unmounted.
When you navigate back, it must be re-mounted, hence re-rendered.

In general, any UI change necessitates a re-render. No way around that - It's kind of "by definition".

You might be able to cache the page.
Or use the `reselect` library to cache expensive to obtain data, so the calculations for re-rendering are quick and minimal.

If react/react-native *thinks* the props have changed (in an already mounted/rendered component), it will also re-render, but you can influence this decision via `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add React.memo to your export of component that reload each time.
So instead of
export default component

you would have:
export default React.memo(component);

Which does a comparison of props and only re-renders if props change (so not on navigate but on actual changes, which is what you want)